# Adding declaration of the member leads to it implicit initialization?

Tags: c++

I have the next class

```
//ChallengeManager.h:
#include "EntityGenerator.h"

class ChallengeManager
    {
    public:
...
    EntityGenerator _entityGenerator; /* With this declaration, constructor of the EntityGenerator will be callen in the ChallengeManager initialization list. If we will comment this out - clear that wan't be */
    static ChallengeManager* _chManager;
    }


//ChallengeManager.cpp:
    ChallengeManager* ChallengeManager::_chManager;

    ChallengeManager::ChallengeManager() : foo()
    {
        _chManager = this;
        //EntityGenerator _entityGenerator();
    }

    ChallengeManager* ChallengeManager::GetChallangeManager()
    {
        return _chManager;
    }

...
```

(ChallengeManager is singleton and i use static method to return reference on it). I need to set 
"_chManager = this" before initializing _entityGenerator because it constructor will call GetChallangeManager().

I am new in C++ and can't understand the next thing. When "EntityGenerator _entityGenerator" declaration in the header file is not commented constructor of the EntityGenerator implicit called by the c++ runtime(i see steps during debugging in VS) in the ChallengeManager initialization list and when is commented - not called. Can't understand why... as i know declaration should not lead to implicit initialization in C++. Can you help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a rule of the language. It is deemed too dangerous to allow for an object to obtain non-initialized user defined types. So non-static data members of user defined types are always initialized, one way or another, when the type containing them is instantiated.

Note that the initialization does not have to be implicit: you can be explicit about it:

```
struct Foo
{
  Foo() {}
  Foo(int i, int j) {}
};

struct Bar
{
  Bar() : f_(42, 42) {} // explicit initialization of data member f_
  Foo f_;
};
```